# 403 forbidden при запуске контейнеров с помощью docker-compose

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose

есть два докер-образа, которые хочу запустить вместе с помощью docker-compose. первый образ - официальный nginx, второй - официальный php. соответственно, хочется чтоб контейнер с nginx проксировал запрос в контейнер с php

структура проекта

```
docker-compose.yml
src/
    php.php
nginx/
    nginx.conf
```

файл `docker-compose.yml` выглядит так

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 88:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    links:
      - php

  php:
    image: php:7.2-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

конфигурация `nginx` такая

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

в файле `php.php` все банально и просто

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

выполняю команду `docker-compose up`, контейнеры поднимаются, в консоли вывод такой

```
Starting nginxphp-2_php_1 ... done
Starting nginxphp-2_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to nginxphp-2_php_1, nginxphp-2_nginx_1
php_1    | [06-Apr-2019 15:23:59] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
php_1    | [06-Apr-2019 15:23:59] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

начинаю обращаться к `localhost:88/php.php`, в консоль падают строки

```
nginx_1  | 2019/04/06 15:25:57 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/php.php" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /php.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:88"
nginx_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2019:15:25:57 +0000] "GET /php.php HTTP/1.1" 403 556 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.75 Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1  | 2019/04/06 15:25:58 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:88", referrer: "http://localhost:88/php.php"
nginx_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2019:15:25:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 556 "http://localhost:88/php.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.75 Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

в браузере красуется надпись

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.15.10
```

при этом все действия в консоли делаю от имени `root'а`, на папку `src` выдавал права `777` и все это не помогает

наведите, пожалуйста, на мысль что и где идет не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `- ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf`

заменить на

- `- ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

[Опционально] Файл `php.php` переименовать в `index.php` и всё замечательно заработает.

Comment: класс... помогло. надо лучше раскурить nginx. спасибо большое!